# Laravel 5 Cookie:get returns null if EncryptCookies turned on

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I'm trying to store some information in cookies in this way:

```
setcookie("o_favourites", serialize($fav_ids), time()+60*60*24*1825);
```

If EncryptCookies is turned on (by adding `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,` presents in `$middleware` section of `app/Http/Kernel.php`) I recieved null when trying to get cookies:

```
$cookie = Cookie::get('o_favourites');
```

What could cause this behaviour?

---

BTW I use setcookies(), because `Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('o_favourites', serialize($fav_ids), null, null, false, false));` seems not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I need to use `Cookie::queue("o_favourites", serialize($fav_ids), time()+60*60*24*1825);` instead `setcookie("o_favourites", serialize($fav_ids), time()+60*60*24*1825);` to set a cookie with encription